# Passing object to JQuery function as options

Tags: jquery, function, object

Not posting the whole function here, but the basic premise is that I'm trying to create a plug-in with options. I'd like not to have to rewrite the entire structure of the function, and I've been Googling for two hours now without any luck.

This is what it looks like now:

```
function slider($rotator_container, settings) {

    var settings = {
        auto_rotate : false,
        auto_rotate_speed : 1000,
        transition_support : true //Disable this to use JQuery animations only
    }
};
```

And I'm calling the variables with the following:

```
slider("main-slider", {auto_rotate:true, auto_rotate_speed:5000});
```

This works if I take the object's deceleration and defaults outside of my function, but the problem is that I call it multiple times on a page so it needs to not be global. How do I go about this? Would I need to rewrite the entire function?

Comment: Why are you shadowing the passed settings with the internal `settings` variable ?

Comment: As a good read: http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/advanced-plugin-concepts/

Comment: @A.Wolff Thanks that is a good read, think I might be able to grab something from here.

Answer (score 2):

In order to have default options you should extend the option using $.extend

```
(function($){
    jQuery.fn.extend({

        // Plugin Name
        slider: function(options) {

            // Defaults options are set here
            // Every default goes within the { } brackets as seen below
            // A comma separates the different values
            var defaults = {  
                auto_rotate : false,
                            auto_rotate_speed : 1000,
                             transition_support : true

            };  
            var options = $.extend(defaults, options); 

return this.each(function() {   


});
}

    });
})(jQuery);
```

Then you can call as

```
$("div").slider(auto_rotate : true});
```

IN your case you can extend object as follows

```
function slider($rotator_container, settings) {

    var defaultsettings = {
        auto_rotate : false,
        auto_rotate_speed : 1000,
        transition_support : true //Disable this to use JQuery animations only
    };
  $.extend( defaultsettings, settings );
)
```

Comment: Thanks I saw this, and I tried this, and I can't get it working without having to restructure the entire function. So is there a way to extend default options as I have it structured in my question?

Comment: In case of yours if you writing a single function and not a plugin , then you need to $.extend( object1, object2 );

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try. Apologies, I'm a designer not a developer :)